# MySQL Stack Procedure Performance Fix, SELECT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, charts, greatest-n-per-group, database-performance

I need to run MYSQL procedure which will select time series records for single point from table pointValues. Of course number of records may be huge - so I need select only 200(limit) of them to draw a chart. I decided to divide all records according following logic :

a) records/(limit/2) -> number of rows in each group
b) get min and max value from each group defined in a).

1. I don't have much experience in high performance querying, so I need some help to improve performance of this procedure.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE secChart 
   (
        id int(11) NOT NULL,
        dataPointId int(11) NOT NULL,
        dataType int(11),
        pointValue DOUBLE NOT NULL,
        ts bigint(20) NOT NULL 
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

   DROP PROCEDURE dataChart;
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dataChart;

   DELIMITER //

   CREATE PROCEDURE dataChart(iter int, step int, pointId int, setStart int,
   ```

   setStop int) 
       BEGIN 
           TRUNCATE TABLE secChart;

   ```
       SET @i = 0;
       SET @iter = iter;
       SET @pointId = pointId; myLoop: 

       WHILE (@i < @iter) 
       DO 
            IF @i = 0 THEN
               SET setStart = 0;
               SET setStop = step-1; 
            END IF; 

            IF @i > 0 THEN
               SET setStart = @i * step;
               SET setStop = setStart + (step-1);
               SET @start = setStart;
               SET @stop = setStop; 
            END IF; **

            INSERT INTO secChart
                (SELECT *
                 FROM pointvalues
                 WHERE dataPointId = @pointId
                   AND (pointValue = (SELECT MIN(pointValue)
                                      FROM 
                                          (SELECT *
                                           FROM flex2.pointvalues
                                           WHERE dataPointId = @pointId
                                           ORDER BY id ASC
                                           LIMIT setStart, setStop) AS b)
                        OR pointValue = (SELECT MAX(pointValue)
                                         FROM
                                             (SELECT *
                                              FROM flex2.pointvalues
                                              WHERE dataPointId = @pointId
                                              ORDER BY id ASC
                                              LIMIT setStart, setStop) AS b2))
                ORDER BY id
                LIMIT 0, 2);**

        SET @i = @i + 1; 

        IF @i > @iter 
        THEN 
            LEAVE myLoop; 
        END IF; 
   END WHILE; 
   END//
   DELIMITER ;

   CALL dataChart(100, 80, 1, 0, 0);
   ```

   For almost 15 000 records it takes 158 sec...

Another select tested by me :

```
INSERT INTO idx
VALUES(@start, @stop , @i, step);

INSERT INTO stt
    (SELECT * 
     FROM
         ((SELECT * 
           FROM
               (SELECT id, pointValue, ts
                FROM flex2.pointvalues AS pv
                WHERE pv.dataPointId = 1
                ORDER BY id
                LIMIT setStart, setStop) AS minval
           ORDER BY pointValue DESC
           LIMIT 0, 1)
          UNION
           (SELECT *  
            FROM
                (SELECT id, pointValue, ts
                 FROM flex2.pointvalues AS pv
                 WHERE pv.dataPointId = 1
                 ORDER BY id
                 LIMIT setStart, setStop) AS maxval
            ORDER BY pointValue ASC
            LIMIT 0, 1)) AS selectScore);
```

For almost 15 000 records it takes 58 sec - quicker but not fast enough.

Third idea is to choose n-rows (for instance 200 rows from 12 000)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM flex2.pointvalues 
WHERE dataPointId = 1 
  AND id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM flex2.pointvalues 
             WHERE dataPointId = 1 
               AND id BETWEEN 
                           (SELECT MIN(id) FROM flex2.pointvalues 
                            WHERE dataPointId = 1) AND 
                           (SELECT MAX(id) FROM flex2.pointvalues 
                            WHERE dataPointId = 1)) 
              AND id % 10 = 0;
```

Best will be to fix performance of idea 2. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First some questions and comments.

- You want to pick evenly spaced points from a time-series set of data?
- Are you doing "candlesticks" (hence the min and max)?
- Don't use any kind of loop; it will be slow.
- Aim for a single `SELECT` (no loop) to grab all the desired items.  SQL is optimized to do such.
- Why are there 5 columns in the table instead of simply 2 (for x and y, aka ts and value)?
- Do you want your chart to be based on time or on index in the table?  There *will* be cases of missing data, so you *will* want to base the chart on *time*.
- Avoid `OFFSET` (ie, `LIMIT m,n`), it has to scan over all the preceding rows; hence slow.

Let's step back.  Instead of getting candlesticks, let's *first* work on a way to use `AVG` instead of `MIN` and `MAX`.  Once you have mastered that, then maybe candlesticks can be done.

```
SELECT FLOOR(ts / 300000) AS '5-minute-intervals',  -- see below
       AVG(value)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE ts ...   -- limit the time span
    GROUP BY 1     -- shorthand, referring to the FLOOR(..)
```

The 300000 assumes a millisecond `ts` (a la Java).  You precomputed that number based on the timespan, based on your "200..." discussion.

That's all there is to it.

Now, for candlesticks:

```
SELECT FLOOR(ts / 300000) AS '5-minute-intervals',
       MIN(value),
       MAX(value)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE ts ...   -- limit the time span
    GROUP BY 1     -- shorthand, referring to the FLOOR(..)
```

And then your chart program needs to take the min and max and somehow turn than into a vertical line.  If you really want certain percentiles instead of min and max, that gets *really* messy.

Getting the intervals...

Please use human readable times.  I really dislike x and y axes that were derived from the data but failed to use "round" numbers.  (Eg, instead of 100, 200, ..., 1500, they use 143, 286, ..., 1432 when the goal was to have about 10 tics, yet they decided that meant *exactly* 10 tics.)

To do that "right" involves finding the overall max and min, doing some arithmetic involving floor() and/or ceil().  And tossing in some heuristics to get "round numbers".  That can be another discussion.  It is purely algorithm -- that could be implemented equally well in either your programming language or SQL.

Comment: Thank You Rick. I have a lot of guidelines which will finally help me to find best solution. Q1:You want to pick evenly spaced points from a time-series set of data? No, it is made by 3rd idea ( select every 10 element)- but It is not satisfying.  Would prefer min/max/average in sub-groups. Comment is limited so I will show my optimized solution. Question is how to transform it into non-loop query.

Comment: I may get firstly min max time stamp for all records and then compute step, but still I won't have 100 min and 100 max values in defined intervals made by one query. Looping may be on java side, bo I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @user4201838 - In most time-based charts, chunking by equal timespans makes sense.  What is your use case where "10 elements" makes more sense?  Anyway, to do such, I would dynamically add an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then chunk based on it (like I was doing with `ts`).

Comment: I will think this through - and I will let you know, how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I optimized my ideas into below solution:

```
`DROP procedure chartSelection;      
 DROP table chartSelectionTable;       
 Delimiter //        
 CREATE PROCEDURE chartSelection(iter int, step int, pointId int, setStart int, setStop int)
 BEGIN
 CREATE temporary TABLE if not exists chartSelectionTable(id int(11) NOT NULL, 
 pointValue double NOT NULL,ts bigint(20) NOT NULL) engine=InnoDB;

TRUNCATE TABLE chartSelectionTable;

SET @i=0;
SET @iter = iter; 
SET @pointId = pointId;
chart: WHILE (@i < @iter)  DO 
IF @i = 0 THEN
    SET setStart = 0; 
    SET setStop = step-1;
END IF;
IF @i >0 THEN
    SET setStart = @i*step;
    SET setStop = setStart + (step-1);
END IF;
     insert into chartSelectionTable(   

     select id, pointValue,ts from (

     select * from pointvalues where (
            id = (select id from( select * from flex2.pointvalues as pv where pv.dataPointId=pointId order by ts limit setStart,setStop) as minval  order by pointValue asc limit 0,1) 
            or
            id = (select id from( select * from flex2.pointvalues as pv where pv.dataPointId=pointId order by ts limit setStart,setStop) as maxval  order by pointValue desc limit 0,1)
      )) as b       
                );

SET @i = @i+1;
IF @i > @iter THEN
    LEAVE chart;
END IF;
END WHILE;
select * from     chartSelectionTable; 
drop table chartSelectionTable;
END//
delimiter ;
```

`

I call it by:
   `CALL chartSelection(100,90,1,0,0);`

But form Java (server level) it is called by:

```
`import java.sql.Statement;
  (...)
 Statement createProcedureStmt = conn.createStatement();`

`createProcedureStmt.execute( "CREATE PROCEDURE `chartSelection` "+
                "(iter int, step int, pointId int, setStart int, setStop int )"+
                " BEGIN "+
                " TRUNCATE TABLE chartSelectionTable;"+
                    " SET @i=0;"+
                    " SET @iter = iter; "+
                    " SET @pointId = pointId;"+
                    " chart: WHILE (@i < @iter)  DO "+
                    " IF @i = 0 THEN"+
                                "   SET setStart = 0;"+ 
                    " SET setStop = step-1;"+
                            " END IF;"+
                        " IF @i >0 THEN"+
                        " SET setStart = @i*step;"+
                        " SET setStop = setStart + (step-1);"+
                            " END IF;"+
                        " insert into chartSelectionTable("+                                 
                                     " select id, pointValue,ts from ("+                                 
                                     " select * from pointvalues where ("+
                                     " id = (select id from( select * from flex2.pointvalues as pv where pv.dataPointId=pointId order by ts limit setStart,setStop) as minval  order by pointValue asc limit 0,1)"+ 
                                            " or"+
                                    " id = (select id from( select * from flex2.pointvalues as pv where pv.dataPointId=pointId order by ts limit setStart,setStop) as maxval  order by pointValue desc limit 0,1)"+
                                    " )) as b       "+
                              "         );"+

                             " SET @i = @i+1;"+
                        " IF @i > @iter THEN"+
                        " LEAVE chart;"+
                        "   END IF;"+
                        " END WHILE;"+
                        " select * from     chartSelectionTable; "+
                    " END ");

        /* Call stored procedure */
        java.sql.CallableStatement stmt = conn
                .prepareCall("{call chartSelection(?,?,?,0,0)}");
        stmt.setInt(1, iteracje);
        stmt.setInt(2, step);
        stmt.setInt(3, dataPointId);`
```

Time of evaluation is reduced about 50%, but still it is too long.  What is changed:
- temporary table instead of real one, 
- selection of only pointValue and time stamp insead of all columns, 
- way of selection.

How to transform it into non-loop solution? How to step out from limits and ordering ?

*---- TO SUM UP ----*
1) I have 1 000 000 records for id = x,
2) I have limit=200 records for chart
3) So in Java I compute - before I call SQL, 1 000 000 / (limit/2) = 10 000 records in 100 groups. 
4) **MAIN ISSUE: select step by step each group ( based on time stamps ) and collect min 
and max (pointValue and time stamp) in group.**